# $_POST with javascript – it works in javascript but not in jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have a form that gets submitted.
Now I would like to retrieve the submitted data with javascript on the next page.

This works just fine when I put it in the body of the html:

```
<script>
    var $_POST = <?php echo json_encode($_POST); ?>;
    document.write($_POST["form_input_name"]);
</script>
```

Now I want to have this functionality in a jQuery plugin method.
I tried the following in my jquery plugin:

```
$.pluginname.test = function() {

    var $_POST = <?php echo json_encode($_POST); ?>;
    document.write($_POST["form_input_name"]);

};
```

But when I try to execute it in the body of the html, I get the following error messages:

> [Error] SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
>
> [Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   '$.pluginname.test')

Why is this code-snipped working in a regular Javascript environment but not when called by a jQuery plugin?

Comment: Is the plugin a `js` file?

Comment: Try this ```var $_POST = "<?php echo json_encode($_POST); ?>";```. Also make sure jQuery is included before it in the body. If it still throws an error use Chrome Developers tools to debug it (set ```debugger``` after ```var $_POST = ...```)

Comment: @chris85 Looks like he is executing it in the body ~  'But when I try to execute it in the body of the html'

Comment: I think error completely different for your thinks. Please add simple "alert('test')" in your function.

Comment: what is it `$.pluginname.test` pluginname in this? is it something like `$.fn.test` the way plugins are created on top of jquery? and it seems that you have a php code in an external js file. if this is the case then it won't work that way.

Comment: the plugin is a `js` file. jQuery is included – everything else in the plugin works just fine. The method is wrapped around `(function($) { ... }(jQuery)); `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PHP tags are being evaluated as JavaScript. That means that PHP is not processing them.

Presumably, this is because you have moved the script to a `.js` file.

While it is possible to generate a JavaScript file from PHP, that won't help you here: The data you are trying to generate is being submitted to the PHP script that generates your HTML document.

Move the script back between `<script>` and `</script>` in the PHP file that generates the HTML.

Answer (score 2):

if this code:

```
$.pluginname.test = function(){};
```

is in external js file then you can't assign a php code values to it. It will cause errors. So i have one solution for it like make a args based plugin like:

```
$.pluginname.test = function(phpObj){
   document.write(phpObj["form_input_name"]);
};
```

and you can call this on your php/html page in the script block like:

```
<script>
    $.selector.test(<?php echo json_encode($_POST); ?>);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a jQuery plugin:

```
$.fn.pluginname = function() {
    var $_POST = 'SOME TEXT HERE';
    $(this).text($_POST);
};

$('.el').pluginname();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bfjLo02m/

*Note: Make sure jQuery is included before*

---

EDIT:

Since you've placed the plugin in a separate .js file you'll need to pass the PHP variables to your plugin in the index.html file. Here is an example:

```
    // pluginname.jquery.js <-- separate file for your plugin
    $.fn.pluginname = function(options) {
        $(this).text(options.var1);
    };

    // index.html (or any html file)
    $('.el').pluginname({ var1: $_POST["somePHPVar"], var2: 'var2Value' });
```